# python prompt with a bash like interface

Tags: python

I am using the python prompt to practice some regular expressions. I was wondering if there was a way to use the up/down arrows (like bash) to cycle through the old commands typed. I know its possible since it works on python on cygwin/windows.
thanks

Comment: Yes on what platform?  Most Linuxes build Python with readline support, but Mac OS X doesn't (or didn't) by default.  There are platform specific ways around this if you don't want to compile, and none of the useful answers below help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [rlcompleter](http://docs.python.org/library/rlcompleter.html) module to get both readline and completion.

Sample PYTHONSTARTUP code:

```
try:
  import readline
except ImportError:
  print "Module readline unavailable."
else:
  import rlcompleter
  readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

Sample .bashrc code to set your python startup file:

```
if [ -f ~/.pythonstartup.py ]
then
  export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonstartup.py
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! This works in my existing python installation without having to install ipython or compiling python with readline support as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

As well as compiling with readline enabled as suggested in another answer, you can also use rlrwrap to add readline at run time, even if it wasn't complied in; like so:

```
rlwrap python
```

Comment: Nice!  This is useful enough that I'd upvote you twice if I could :).

Answer (score 6):

You want [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/).

Answer (score 6):

If you compile python with readline support, the REPL environment should do this for you.